# stop ResultSet from firing pop-ups when database table has no records

Tags: java, sql

I have the intention of creating pop-ups when a particular table has records and when there are no records in that table, the pop-ups will stop showing.
the pop-ups serves as a notification to the user on tasks that has been done(record entries) and when the user confirms he has seen those records, the records will be deleted and the pop-ups wont show until there are records entered into the table again for another confirmation.

I used ScheduledExecutorService to create a runtime for the method where this code must check the ResultSet every 10 seconds for records and if there are no records, the method won't be fired.

```
try{
    String sql="select * from confirm_purchase";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.first()){
     Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             int d2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"new purchased item(s) have been recorded.\ndo you wish to view them?","view current items purchased",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
             if(d2==0){
                 confirmItemPurchase cip = new confirmItemPurchase();
                 cip.setVisible(true);
             }
         }
     };
   ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); 
   service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }else{
    System.out.println("no data yet");
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }finally{
    try{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      }
    }
```

This code works fine and the pop-ups appear. but when the records are cleared in the table, the pop-up still shows up.

How do I stop the pop-up from showing when there are no records in the table.

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exception, and you'll know what the exception is, its message, etc. Allowing you to find out what's wrong. If you don't understand it, then post it. And also, read the javadoc of the methods you're using: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first--.

Comment: there is no exception in this @JB_Nizet. am thinking the resultSet doesn't close properly when the table has no records. if the app is started when the table has no records, the pop-ups don't show. but if the app is started with records in the table and these records are deleted then the pop-ups keep showing until the app is stopped and restarted

Comment: So the popup you're asking about is the one displayed by `showConfirmDialog(null,"new purchased item(s) have been recorded.\ndo you wish to view them?","view current items purchased",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);`? Your code schedules the display of that popup every 10 seconds. Why do you think it should ever stop displaying?

Comment: because it must only display if the resultSet has records. So the method checks the select statement I wrote and prepares a resultSet to hold records from the select statement. if resultSet is not empty, pop-up must show and if its empty pop-up must not show. the public void run(){} must check the resultSet every 10 seconds to display the required result @JB_Niizet

Comment: Well, the answer is in your comment. You currently execute a request once, check the resultset once, and then display a popup every 10 seconds. Apparently what you actually want is to execute a request and check the resultset every 10 seconds, check the resultset every 10 seconds, and the display the popup if the resultset is not empty.

Comment: hmmm ok will try to re-structure the code